# bing speech api speech to text duration statistics

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have a .wav file which has a single sentence.
Does Bing Speech api analyze .wav files which can convert speech to text. What I would like to know is does bing speech api can give me statistics like example
input .wav file: "This is linda"

output: word: this duration: 5ms
        word: is duration: 2ms
        word: linda duration: 5ms
pause duration: 2ms
        total duration : 12ms

Comment: Looking at the [response JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest?tabs=Powershell#process-the-speech-recognition-response) there is a `duration`. Is that what you need? It's not very clear whether it's in milliseconds or anything, though. It looks like it's for the entire text and not per word.

Comment: any suggestions. I have a sentence and related voice for the sentence. on the UI I would like to highlight the word in the sentence  show as the voice (wav file) reads it out.

Comment: I'm testing the platform myself and would like to know about these features.  Also, how to deal with initial silence.